# Ubuntu Allow users access to roots "screen" command, also restrict which screens they can attach to

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-14.04, gnu-screen

I'm trying to allow a user to connect to the screens that the root user has. When another user does `"screen -ls"`, it shows `"No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-USERNAMEHERE"`.

In addition to this, is it possible to restrict users to individual screens? For example, I don't want **user1** to attach to **screen1**, but I want them to be able to attach to **screen2**.

Thanks,
Toby.

Comment: To list accessible screens belonging to another user use `screen -ls username/`.

Comment: Great to know! This comes up with "Must run suid root for multiuser support.", which I've googled. I've enabled multiuser with "Ctrl-a :multiuser on" and "Ctrl-a :acladd USERHERE" but when I type screen -ls USERHERE/ nothing shows up still.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have only been using it to let root connect to a non-root screen. That may explain why I didn't need to make it suid. But I only used that on Debian, so I don't know if there might be any difference between Ubuntu and Debian.

Comment: @kasperd Usually Ubuntu and Debian are quite similar. Have you got any suggestions for a non-root connecting to a root screen?

Thanks!

Comment: I would first become root through any of the usual means and then attach to the screen. Changing `screen` to be suid if it wasn't already means you would be opening a possible attack vector for an intruder to gain root privileges.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can tell `screen` to share with one user at a time.

In order for this to work, you must have SELinux enabled and screen must run as `suid` root - both of which are the defa

### Host

**1. Create session**

First, create a new screen session:

```
$ screen -d -m -S session_name
```

Attach to it:

```
$ screen -r session_name
```

**2. Turn on multiuser support**

From within `screen'; type` Ctrl+a` and type

```
:multiuser on
```

Or from a outside the `screen` session, type:

```
$ screen -S session_name -X multiuser on
```

**3. Give access to a user**

From within screen, type `Ctrl+a` and type:

```
:acladd guest_username # the username to share your screen with
```

Or from outside a `screen` session, type:

```
$ screen -S session_name -X acladd guest_username
```

You could run this line programmatically to give access to a list of users.

**4. Share session information**

You can share your username `<host_username>` and the `screen` session name `<session_name>` with the guest so they can connect.

Hitting, `Ctrl+a d` lets you leave the session without closing `screen`

### Guest

Armed with the access, the screen session name and the host username, the guest can connect to the screen session:

```
screen -x host_username/session_name
```

The guest should now have access to the host's `screen` session